# Is `daemonUser` really the correct owner of the `defaultLinuxInstallLocation` files?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

Using the `DockerPlugin` with the defaults, the image is created with a `WORKDIR` of `/opt/docker`, and all the files under it are owned by `demiourgos728`. The user is not a system user because that's "best practice". But should the user have the ability to modify the application files?

I'm thinking that if there were an exploit to the application that allowed the user to `chmod +w` and modify the application files, malware could somehow use that to gain further permissions. I don't have a particular strategy in mind, just spitballing.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the user has not the ability to change any files. This has been reported multiple times and it should be so. Usually people want to write log files. However for this use case you should mount external volumes or log to an external system.

Hope that helps
Muki

Comment: That's not true; it is possible to change files within the container; the last layer of the Docker image is writable. There are even Docker plugin settings in `sbt-native-packager` to support setting permissions.
https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats/docker.html#environment-settings
I have even used them for creating a writable `logs` directory and seen it populated.

Comment: I just verified it on one of my containers: I can shell into it, `chmod u+w` the main shell script, and truncate it.

Comment: The default chmod type is read/execute. https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Fcom%2Ftypesafe%2Fsbt%2Fpackager%2Fdocker%2FDockerPlugin.scala .

Comment: Yes. And…? As long as the owner of the files is the same as the owner of the server process, the process can change the permissions at will. Compromising the process can lead to compromising the files that the process runs. That seem to me to open an extra avenue for malicious code.